# Japanese terms for an attribute and adverbial (part of a sentence)

Tags: terminology

What are the correct terms for:

**attribute** (a part of sentence) as a word or phrase that is syntactically subordinate to another and serves to limit, identify, particularize, describe, or supplement the meaning of the form with which it is in construction?

**adverbial** (or adverbial modifier) - a word or phrase functioning as an adverb.

For an attribute I could only find 属性{ぞくせい} and 限定{げんてい} and for adverbial 副詞句{ふくしく} and 副詞節{ふくしせつ}. Are these terms commonly used in the linguistic community?

Also, what is a term for "part of sentence"? I know part of speech is 品詞{ひんし}, but cannot find how to say "part of sentence". Is 文の部分 an appropriate term?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure, but...

For **attribute** I think you might be looking for [修飾語]{しゅう・しょく・ご}; for **adverbial**, [付加語]{ふ・か・ご} or [副詞類]{ふく・し・るい}.

For **part of sentence**, [文]{ぶん}の[成分]{せい・ぶん} is what you want.

Check out the [Wikipedia entry for 文の成分](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%96%87%E3%81%AE%E6%88%90%E5%88%86).

Comment: I am afraid the term adjunct includes both attribute and adverbial: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/adjunct

Comment: @user1602:    What?  You did not mention the word "adjunct" in your question...

Comment: But you used it in you answer :) 付加語

Comment: @user1602:  Oh, I did not notice that in the Wikipedia page.